# List of all smart contract based attacks?

Tags: contract-development, security

Do you know of a list/blog/webiste with all attacks that occurred against smart contracts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find an extended description of the well known attacks and the security measures to take while writing your smat contract in the official doc.

 please check https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Safety

Answer (score 5):

ConsenSys maintains a list of best practices, and explains how the patterns protects against attacks: https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices

Answer (score 3):

You can also take a look at this survey for "Attacks on Ethereum Smart Contracts"

https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1007.pdf

They have listed the type of attacks along with use cases as well.

Hope this information helps.